# Difference between appSettings and connectionStrings in Web.config file?

Tags: asp.net

Why is there another section called connectionStrings?  I have always just used appSettings, until I noticed this in a new project:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="SqlConnString" value="server=ABC;database=ABC;uid=A;pwd=B;"/>
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>    
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there a difference?  Any reason why I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx):

> The connectionStrings element
>   specifies a collection of database
>   connection strings, as name/value
>   pairs, for ASP.NET applications and
>   features.
>
> In previous versions of ASP.NET,
>   connection strings were stored in the
>   appSettings. In ASP.NET 2.0, features,
>   such as Session, Membership,
>   Personalization, and Role Manager,
>   rely on connection strings that are
>   stored in the connectionStrings
>   element. You can also use the
>   connectionStrings element to store
>   connection strings for your own
>   applications.

So the only real difference is that the baked-in ASP.NET 2.0 features will expect their connection strings to be in the connectionStrings area.

Comment: Why couldn't Session, Membership, Personalization and Role Manager just have leveraged app settings? What additional functionality do connection strings provide that app settings don't?

Answer (score 2):

If you separate your connection strings into the `<connectionStrings>` section, your config will be easier to read, maintain, and handle.

Also, furthermore, you could increase your security by encrypting just the connection strings since those typically are the sensitive items, and if they're in their own section, you can easily just encrypt that one section and leave the rest of your app.config in plain text, so you can easily update and modify settings.

Marc

Comment: You can just as easily encrypt app settings.  As for the separation, I can think of many different ways to organize appsettings besides connection strings vs appsettings.  I hope that there was more to MSFT's decision to introduce this separation than what Eric mentioned.  This seems arbitrary otherwise.

Comment: In addition, this decision seems to have weird side effects today.  In Azure App Service Plans, you can configure Application Settings (both app settings and connection strings).  However, application configuration does not override app.config app settings while connection strings do override app.config connection strings.  Because of this, I am now putting non-connection string settings in connection strings simply for the overriding capability of connection strings.  I don't find this easier to read, maintain or handle.

Comment: @Paul - Application Settings set in the portal DO override appSettings in your website's web.config or your webjob's app.config file. I use this all the time.

Comment: I will have to try this again.  This didn't appear to be working for me.